# what does offsets mean in pytorch nn.EmbeddingBag?

Tags: pytorch

I know offsets meaning when it has two numbers, but what does it mean when more than two numbers,for example:

```
weight = torch.FloatTensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
embedding_sum = nn.EmbeddingBag.from_pretrained(weight, mode='sum')
print(list(embedding_sum.parameters()))
input = torch.LongTensor([0,1])
offsets = torch.LongTensor([0,1,2,1])

print(embedding_sum(input, offsets))
```

the result is :

```
[Parameter containing:
tensor([[1., 2., 3.],
        [4., 5., 6.]])]
tensor([[1., 2., 3.],
        [4., 5., 6.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]])
```

who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/0ec717c83097c4600e883a860d673226a08fcda4/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py#L145-L147),

```
return F.embedding(
    input, self.weight, self.padding_idx, self.max_norm,
    self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)
```

It uses the [functional embedding bag](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#embedding-bag), which explains the `offsets` parameters as

> **offsets** (LongTensor, optional) – Only used when input is 1D. offsets determines the starting index position of each bag (sequence) in input.

In the [`EmbeddingBag` docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.EmbeddingBag.html#embeddingbag):

> If input is 1D of shape (N), it will be treated as a concatenation of multiple bags (sequences). offsets is required to be a 1D tensor containing the starting index positions of each bag in input. **Therefore, for offsets of shape (B), input will be viewed as having B bags.** Empty bags (i.e., having 0-length) will have returned vectors filled by zeros.

The last statement *("Empty bags (i.e., having 0-length) will have returned vectors filled by zeros.")* explains the zero vectors in your resulting tensor.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

weight = torch.FloatTensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
embedding_sum = nn.EmbeddingBag.from_pretrained(weight, mode='sum')
print(embedding_sum.weight)

""" output
Parameter containing:
tensor([[1., 2., 3.],
        [4., 5., 6.]])
"""
```

```py
input = torch.LongTensor([0, 1])
offsets = torch.LongTensor([0, 1, 2, 1])
```

According to these offsets you will get the following samples

```py
"""
sample_1: input[0:1] # tensor([0])
sample_2: input[1:2] # tensor([1])
sample_3: input[2:1] # tensor([])
sample_4: input[1:]  # tensor([1])
"""
```

Embedding the samples above

```py
# tensor([0]) => lookup 0  => embedding_sum.weight[0] => [1., 2., 3.]
# tensor([1]) => lookup 1  => embedding_sum.weight[1] => [4., 5., 6.]
# tensor([])  => empty bag                            => [0., 0., 0.]
# tensor([1]) => lookup 1  => embedding_sum.weight[1] => [4., 5., 6.]

print(embedding_sum(input, offsets))

""" output
tensor([[1., 2., 3.],
        [4., 5., 6.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [4., 5., 6.]])
"""
```

One more example:

```py
input = torch.LongTensor([0, 1])
offsets = torch.LongTensor([0, 1, 0])
```

According to these offsets you will get the following samples

```py
"""
sample_1: input[0:1] # tensor([0])
sample_2: input[1:0] # tensor([])
sample_3: input[0:]  # tensor([0, 1])
"""
```

Embedding the samples above

```py
# tensor([0])    => lookup 0 => embedding_sum.weight[0] => [1., 2., 3.]
# tensor([])     => empty bag => [0., 0., 0.]
# tensor([0, 1]) => lookup 0 and 1 then reduce by sum 
#                => embedding_sum.weight[0] + embedding_sum.weight[1] => [5., 7., 9.]

print(embedding_sum(input, offsets))

""" output
tensor([[1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [5., 7., 9.]])
"""
```